# AWK script to check first line of a file and then print the rest

Tags: regex, bash, awk, fasta

I am trying to write an AWK script to parse a file of the form

```
> field1 - field2 field3 ...
lineoftext
anotherlineoftext
anotherlineoftext
```

and I am checking using regex if the first line is correct (begins with a > and then has something after it) and then print all the other lines. This is the script I wrote but it only verifies that the file is in a correct format and then doesn't print anything.

```
#!/bin/bash
# FASTA parser

awk ' BEGIN { x = 0; }
{ if ($1 !~ />.*/ && x == 0)
    { print "Not a FASTA file"; exit; }
  else { x = 1; next; }
  print $0 }
END { print " - DONE - "; }'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you can use the following awk command:

```
awk 'NR==1 && /^>./ {p=1} p' file
```

On the first row `NR==1` it checks whether the line starts with a `>` followed by "something" (`/^>./`). If that condition is true the variable `p` will be set to one. The `p` at the end checks whether `p` evaluates true and prints the line in that case.

If you want to print the error message, you need to revert the logic a bit:

```
awk 'NR==1 && !/^>./ {print "Not a FASTA file"; exit 1} 1' file
```

In this case the program prints the error messages and exits the program if the first line does not start with a `>`. Otherwise all lines gets printed because `1` always evaluates to true.

Comment: I am very new to awk. Shouldn't there also be a matching operator (~) to check for the regular expression? And doesn't the caret character negate what comes before it? And how does the p at the end work in making awk print the line?

Comment: If you just pass a regex in the condition, awk will match it against the whole line. No `~` is required. The caret character only negates a character class when used inside it, like `[^ab]`. When used outside a character class, it marks the *begin of the string*. Simply writing `p` is the same as `p==true { print }` meaning p will get evaluated as a boolean condition and `print` is the default action in awk.

Comment: The OP's description is incomplete.  A valid FASTA file can have any number of these records.  The line with a wedge is a header which indicates the start of a new record.  So the provided script implements what the OP describes but is not generally useful for validating FASTA files.

Comment: @tripleee Following the specification on Wikipedia a FASTA file can contain many of those sections but needs to contain at least one. IMHO the check is valid.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for pointing out the error in my script. I know that the FASTA specification allows for multiple records in a single file but I am still new to awk and I wanted to get the hang of making it work for single-record files, but yes you are correct, it is not correct per the FASTA specification.

Comment: Why is it that the + is unnecessary in the regex?

Comment: @andreas.vitikan think it through. What does `.` mean in a regexp? What does `+` mean in a regexp? So then what does `.+` mean?

Comment: . means any character that is not a whitespace. And + plus means 1 or more repetitions of the preceding token.

Comment: `.` does NOT mean any character that is not a white space, it just means any character. So the `.` tells you you have at least one character after the `>` and that is your stated requirement. Now when you add the `+` it tells you you have one or more characters - nothing useful about that wrt your requirement to have at least 1 character, the `.` already told you that is true. Using a trailing `+` (or `*`) is usually only useful when you are capturing the text that matches the regexp for later use.

Answer (score 2):

For this OP literally

```
awk 'NR==1{p=$0~/^>/}p' YourFile
# shorter version with info of @EdMorton
awk 'NR==1{p=/^>/}p' YourFile
```

for line after > (including)

```
awk '!p{p=$0~/^>/}p' YourFile
# shorter version with info of @EdMorton
awk '!p{p=/^>/}p' YourFile
```

Comment: You don't even need the `$0~` since `/foo/` is shorthand for `$0~/foo/`.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you care about is the first line, you can just check that, then exit.

```
awk 'NR > 1 { exit (0) }
    ! /^>/ { print "Not a FASTA file" >"/dev/stderr"; exit (1) }' file
```

As noted in comments, the `>"/dev/stderr"` is a nonportable hack which may not work for you.  Regard it as a placeholder for something slightly more sophisticated if you want a tool which behaves as one would expect from a standard Unix tool (run silently if no problems; report problems to standard error).

Comment: The portable way to print to stderr is `print | "cat>&2"`. Using `print > "/dev/stderr"` will only work in gawk and a couple of other awks. If you think `/dev/stderr` is a literal file name - consider the surprise you'd get running this from a shell script that earlier had `exec 2>&1`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Special-FD.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the heads-up. I'm imagining these complications are out of scope for a beginning Awk programmer, although they are of course correct.

Comment: Agreed but you should either state that `print > "/dev/stderr"` is non-portable or just don't use it otherwise how's a beginner to guess and debug that if it doesn't work as expected on their system?

Comment: Thanks for feedback and suggestion.  Updated now.